# In odoo I want to make group by field in search view but this field Json type so how can I make that?

Tags: python, odoo

In odoo I want to make group by field in search view but this field Json type so how can I make that, this the field: analytic_distribution = fields.Json(inverse="_inverse_analytic_distribution",)

I'm trying to add like any field but when I select it in group by the data appeared like [object Object]